# Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires that 'String.Index' conform to 'RangeExpression'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple function:

```
private func formatted(phoneNumber: String, mask: String) -> String {
    var output = ""
    var index = phoneNumber.startIndex
    for character in mask where index < phoneNumber.endIndex {
        if character == "_" {
            output += phoneNumber[index] //hers is an error
            index = phoneNumber.index(after: index)
        } else {
            output += String(character)
        }
    }
    return output
}
```

What should I do to fix that error?

How do I call it?

```
formatted(phoneNumber: "12345678", mask: " ___ __ ___") // " 123 45 678"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the string subscript returns a `Character`, but [`+=`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2965662) can only be used to add a sequence of characters to a string:

```
static func += <Other>(lhs: inout String, rhs: Other) where Other : Sequence, Character == Other.Element
```

Hence Swift resolves the subscript to the subscript that takes a range and returns a `Substring`, and says that `index` is not a range.

You can create a `CollectionOfOne`/`String`/`Array` out of the character and then use `+=` to concatenate

```
output += CollectionOfOne(phoneNumber[index])
```

or just:

```
output.append(phoneNumber[index])
```

The same thing applies to the else branch too :)

Comment: Or simply pass a `ClosedRange` which would result in a subsequence of a single element instead of the element itself which is exactly what the error is trying to communicate `phoneNumber[index...index]`